# How can I get unique IPv4 and IPv6 visitor counts on nginx access.log in shell?

Tags: nginx, ipv6, ipv4, logging

How do I get some stats on unique IPv4 and IPv6 visitors by looking at a nginx access.log with UNIX CLI?

I use the standard `combined` pre-defined format for `access_log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a summary on the number of unique IPv4 and IPv6 visitors in the last two days:

```
grep "1[89]/Feb/" /var/www/logs/mdoc.su/mdoc.su.access.log | \
cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq | sed "s#.*\..*#.#g;s#.*:.*#:#g" | \
sort | uniq -c ; echo ipv4 and ipv6 unique hosts, summary ; date
```

To get a summary on the number of unique IPv4/24 and IPv6/48 subnets of the unique visitors in the last two days:

```
grep "1[89]/Feb/" /var/www/logs/mdoc.su/mdoc.su.access.log | \
cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq | sed -E "s#^(([0-9a-f]+[.:]){3}).*#\1#g" | \
uniq | sed "s#.*\..*#.#g;s#.*:.*#:#g" | sort | uniq -c ; \
echo ipv4 and ipv6 unique IPv4/24 and IPv6/48 subnets, summary ; date
```

To see the most popular IPv4 and IPv6 subnets of the unique visitors in the last two days:

```
grep "1[89]/Feb/" /var/www/logs/mdoc.su/mdoc.su.access.log | \
cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq | sed -E "s#^(([0-9a-f]+[.:]){3}).*#\1#g" | \
uniq -c | sort -rn | head -16 ; \
echo ipv4 and ipv6 unique IPv4/24 and IPv6/48 nets, most popular nets ; date
```